# Decrease No.of days by 1 daily from MySQL Column

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I want to decrease the number of days by 1 daily. And update the remaining days in the same row and column.
Below you can see my MySQL table :
[image: users table]

In the above image, you can see that I have a column "licence_validity" that contains the number of days and you can also see I have another column "activated_on" now this column will be filled when licence get activated with the current date.
Now I want to decrease the number of days by 1 daily in the licence_validity column when activated_on column has a date.

Comment: You can use [`DATEDIFF()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to decrease the number of days by 1 daily in the licence_validity column when activated_on column has a date.

I am understanding this correctly, that's a simple `update`:

```
update users
set license_validity = license_validity - 1
where activated_on is not null
```

If you want to do this on a daily basis, then you might want to use the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html). Something like:

```
create event event_update_users
on schedule every 1 day
do
    update users
    set license_validity = license_validity - 1
    where activated_on is not null;
```

Comment: Can you please show me how can I do this by event scheduler? @GMB

Comment: @DCodeMania: I don't understand your question. This is a SQL statement, that you do run in your sql client (php my admin, if that's what you are using).

Comment: in my case it decreased my date by 1 second, my column type is `datetime`